# What is actually going on in your brain during a night terror?

Tags: sleep, dreams

I used to have really bad night terrors back in the day, where I would think I was floating and I would wake up and actually my vision would be very fuzzy - so I just want to know..

What is actually going on in your brain during a night terror? Is there any evidence that the type of bed one sleeps on makes any difference in lowering the incidence of night terrors?

Comment: Welcome to the site Philip! We appreciate some background research on this site prior to asking a question. Next time look for some sources yourself you can describe your question in a bit more detail. I hope UV-D's answer provided you with some initial insights. Perhaps you can even ask follow up questions (in new posts) in case you don't understand anything about the given answer.

Answer (score 5):

Night terrors, a type of parasomnia has been the subject of considerable study.

According to ["Insights from studying human sleep
disorders"](http://aegean.psychology.uiowa.edu/Faculty/Blumberg/Course_Docs/Seminar.2008/Readings/Mahowald.Schenck.pdf) (Mahowald and Schenck, 2005), parasomnias are in two categories:

> The common parasomnias are another example of
>   ‘dissociated sleep states’, representing the simultaneous admixture of
>   wakefulness and either NREM sleep (disorders of arousal such as
>   sleepwalking or sleep terrors) or wakefulness and REM sleep (REM
>   sleep behaviour disorder). Parasomnias may result in striking clinical
>   phenomena, which appear as the brain becomes reorganized across
>   states, and are therefore apt to occur during the transition from one
>   state to another.

Sleep terrors are an example of NREM sleep disorder and are usually the result of febrile illness, sleep deprivation, physical activity, emotional stress and medications - so the question about the bed can relate, particularly if the bed is causing lack of sleep.